# Problems uninstalling SEO Boss extension in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I have created a website named `www.connectedipvoice.com` and installed SEO Boss extension. Somehow it was not working so I tried to remove it using my administrator mode from my website but it shows a message:

> JFolder: :delete: Path is not a folder. Path: /home/content/54/9492054/html/components/com_seoboss
>   Component Uninstall: Can't uninstall. Please remove manually

Then I tried to uninstall directly from server but it's not showing there too. My problem is when I try to install it again - it's showing me that the file is already installed and when I checked in the *extension area* >
*manage* catagory I found that SEO Boss extension is still there. But now I'm unable to get the options to remove it - the status column becomes blank!

Answer (score 4):

To properly uninstall it (so you can install it again) you need to also remove the component reference inside the table called #__extensions

Search the element field for anything containing "com_seoboss" and delete it.

Then you should be able to install it again.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but already tried that before posting the topic :|

Answer (score 1):

You should also look for this and delete it - /home/content/54/9492054/html/administrator/components/com_seoboss

Comment: sorry sir but com_seoboss was not there already tried thanks for your efforts meanwhile i got another temporary solution for this !!!

Comment: @Hardy What was the temporary solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what you mean by 'i tried to uninstall directly from the server'.
Anyway, I have had a similar issue to you when I was trying to uninstall virtuemart from a website. What worked for me was to:

1. manually delete all the component folders (using an FTP client like [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) )
2. manually delete all component tables from the database (using phpMyAdmin)

If you try this solution, make sure you backup your database first.
Hope this helps.

Comment: what i mean by live server is what u suggest me to do via ftp client to access my server remotly to our desktop !!!